# playing audio when apps running

Tags: ios, audio, xcode4, xcode4.3

I've been trying lately to get my app to play a sound from when it open to when its closed and I'm have difficulty. I have some code on playing a sound when I press a button and it's fine I'm just wondering if there is any tweaks I could do to make it play on its own and from the start or is there a way I could say press play and make the sound loop why I'm playing the game.

.h

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


    - (IBAction)t1:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)t1:(id)sender {

    CFBundleRef mainbundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileUrlRef;
    soundFileUrlRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainbundle, (CFStringRef) @"t1", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileUrlRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about trying AVAudioPlayer and turning on the continuous playback by setting number of loops to -1:

```
    myPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1

    [myPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [myPlayer play];


    //when application did enter background or something
    [myPlayer stop];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Also make sure your Audio Sessions are set properly for background playback:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Basics/Basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW2

Comment: You'll need to initialize the audio player and give it a source audio file...something like this: 
AVAudioPlayer *myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:[NSData      dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audioFile" ofType:@"wav"]] error:nil];

Comment: also, you probably want to make the player a class property so you can access it from multiple places, in which case you would probably have either self.myPlayer or _myPlayer